# jQuery Validation javascript defined rules not working

Tags: php, jquery, validation

This works...

```
<input type="text" id="valid" width="200px" minlength="5" />
```

This does not...

```
<input type="text" id="valid" width="200px" />

...

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#validationform').validate({
        rules: {
            valid: {
                minlength:5
            }
        },
        messages: {
            valid: {
                minlength: "Need more characters"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The javascript is saved off in a file `validationrules.js` that is linked in the head section.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/validationrules.js"></script>
```

I'm probably missing something very simple. What is it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: an input name maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `input` name is missing

> A name attribute is required on the element firstly because that's
>   what jQuery validate uses internally as a key for each field, and
>   secondly because the name attribute is required on input elements to
>   ensure the page validates to the specified DOCTYPE.

Code:

```
<input type="text" id="valid" name="valid" width="200px" />
```

Comment: *facepalm* Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, and i use this plugin before. The code should contain rules, field name etc.

```
<form id="myform">
<label for="field">Required: </label>
<input type="text" class="left" id="field" name="field">
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
```

Declaration :

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true
      }
   }
});
```